# Dynamic <li></li>for news ticker

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, wordpress

hi I'm fetching JSON data from wordpress site AND converting title into

as below:

```
<?php $get=file_get_contents("https://www.thekashmirmonitor.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=192");
$var=json_decode($get);
$km=array();
foreach($var as $data)
{ $km[]=$data->title->rendered;} ?>
```

ok after fetching title im printing output as

```
<div class="section-container">
<div class="bn-breaking-news" id="newsTicker5">
<div class="bn-label">#News:</div>
<div class="bn-news">
    <ul>

                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[0]; ?>&nbsp;</li>
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[1]; ?>&nbsp;</li>
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[2]; ?>&nbsp;</li>
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[3]; ?>&nbsp;</li> 
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[4]; ?>&nbsp;</li> 
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[5]; ?>&nbsp;</li> 
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[6]; ?>&nbsp;</li> 
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[7]; ?>&nbsp;</li> 
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[8]; ?>&nbsp;</li>
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[9]; ?>&nbsp;</li>
                             <li>&nbsp;<?php echo $km[10]; ?>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="bn-controls">
    <button><span class="bn-arrow bn-prev"></span></button>
    <button><span class="bn-action"></span></button>
    <button><span class="bn-arrow bn-next"></span></button>
</div>
```

suppose if the JSON result have only 3 records,

but my ticker has `<li` counts from 0 - 10
it will fetch only 3 records and rest `<li>` will print empty news ticker
SO: All i want is to create `<li>` dynamically
i.e No of json title = No. OF `<li>`
in my case let it will be x, so it will generate `<li>` X xtimes

Comment: the last paragraph of your question is a bit unclear. Do you simply want to print only 3 <li> when there are 3 news? Is that the question?

Comment: Yes i want to print on based of json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems a little unclear but I believe you wish to display a`li` element for each title and not have any empty li elements?
It's a very simple task to iterate through the array and add a `li` element as you go.

```
$url='https://www.thekashmirmonitor.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=192';
$json=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $json as $obj )printf('<li>%s</li>',$obj->title->rendered);
echo '</ul>';
```

This will output

- IVR Institute takes action against 3 Kashmiri girls for ‘adverse remarks’ against Army
- 5 held for assault on Kashmiri trader in West Bengal
- 69 killed as massive fire breaks out in chemical warehouses in Bangladesh capital
- SC to hear tomorrow plea for protection of Kashmiris from threats after Pulwama Attack
- We want Kashmir, But Not Kashmiris: Chidambaram points out the ‘Depressing Irony’
- Fresh snowfall, landslides shut Srinagar-Jammu highway

Reading the question again after comments made I think I misunderstood. There will be a maximum of 10 items in the list but f there should be fewer than 10 results the menu should not display empty `li` elements...?

Modified the above and wrapped in a function to which you need only supply the ID for the feed and, optionally, a maximum count.

```
function createlist( $id, $max=10 ){
    $url=sprintf( 'https://www.thekashmirmonitor.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=%d', $id );
    $json=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );

    if( !empty( $json ) ){
        $html=[];
        $html[]=sprintf('<ul data-feed=%d>',$id );
        foreach( $json as $i => $obj ){
            if( $i < $max )$html[]=sprintf( '<li>%s</li>',$obj->title->rendered );
        }
        $html[]='</ul>';
    }
    return implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
}

$ticker_max_count=10;

echo createlist( 190, $ticker_max_count );
echo createlist( 191, $ticker_max_count );
echo createlist( 192, $ticker_max_count );
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
<div class="bn-news">
<ul>
<?php
     foreach($km as $value) {
          echo "<li>" . $value . "</li>";
     }
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That alone will not set a maximum execution of 10 times in the loop. A fixed counter and a conditional could do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop ten times, but also make sure not to print empty list items you could try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
   if (isset($km[$i])) { 
       echo "<li>&nbsp $km[$i] &nbsp</li>\n";
   } else {
       exit;
   }
}
```

This will print the items 10 times if at least 10 items exist, but if the index does not exist it will exit the loop.

The other way you could do it is with a foreach:

```
foreach ($km as $key=>$value) {
   if ($key < 10) { 
       echo "<li>&nbsp $value &nbsp</li>\n";
   } else {
       exit;
   }
}
```

It checks the key of each item and only prints if the key is less than 10 (`$km[0]` - `$km[9]`).

Both of these solutions have about the same amount of code and should satisfy your requirements. I can't really say one is better than the other